# How to Archive two strings into NSData by using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.6, nskeyedarchiver

I have NSMutableArray  and a NSString. 
How to archive these  two in to a NSData by using NSKeyedArchiver in IOS6, Xcode4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
// Convert it  to NSdata

    NSData *messageData1 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:message];
    NSData *messageData2 = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr];
```

Comment: can I combine these two results.

Comment: make dictionary of array and string and than archive it. try :)